# Definition of Scalar and Vector Potentials

Tags: potential, vector-fields

So, I'm looking at one demonstration of the Helmholtz decomposition, which uses in a simple, yet nice way, the identity for the 3d Dirac's Delta:
\begin{equation}
\delta^3(\mathfrak{r})=-\frac{1}{4\pi}\nabla^2\bigg(\frac{1}{\mathfrak{r}}\bigg)
\end{equation}
$\mathfrak{r}$ being, of course, the separation vector $|r-r'|$. I was able to follow it properly, but stumbled on the definition used for the scalar and vector potentials, which are some quite fundamental ones. So, suppose $\mathcal{F}_1$ and $\mathcal{F}_2$ are, respectively, solenoidal and irrotational vector fields in $\mathbb{R}^3$. One allows itself to define the scalar potential $\Phi(\mathbf{r})$ and the vector potential $\mathbf{A(r)}$ as it follows:
\begin{align}
&\mathbf{\Phi(r)}=\frac{1}{4\pi}\int_{\mathbb{R}^3}\frac{\nabla'\cdot\mathcal{F}_1(\mathbf{r'})}{\mathfrak{r}}\ d^3\mathbf{r'}\\
&\\
&\mathbf{A(r)}=\mathbf{\Phi(r)}=\frac{1}{4\pi}\int_{\mathbb{R}^3}\frac{\nabla'\times\mathcal{F}_2(\mathbf{r'})}{\mathfrak{r}}\ d^3\mathbf{r'}
\end{align}
I mean, I know that scalar and vector potentials are defined in terms of curl-free and div-free fields, but I do not understand why, and how one would define them in such a way as that above. Further, if you restrict your domain to a bounded subset $\mathcal{V}\subseteq\mathbb{R}^3$, you now consider the surface $\mathcal{S}$ which encloses this domain, namely:
\begin{align}
&\mathbf{\Phi(r)}=\frac{1}{4\pi}\bigg[\int_{\mathcal{V}}\frac{\nabla'\cdot\mathcal{F}_1(\mathbf{r'})}{\mathfrak{r}}\ d^3\mathbf{r'}-\oint_{\mathcal{S}}\hat{\mathbf{n}}\cdot\frac{\mathcal{F}_1(\mathbf{r'})}{\mathfrak{r}}d^2\mathbf{r'}\bigg]\\
&\\
&\mathbf{A(r)}=\mathbf{\Phi(r)}=\frac{1}{4\pi}\int_{\mathcal{V}}\frac{\nabla'\times\mathcal{F}_2(\mathbf{r'})}{\mathfrak{r}}\ d^3\mathbf{r'}-\oint_{\mathcal{S}}\hat{\mathbf{n}}\cdot\frac{\mathcal{F}_2(\mathbf{r'})}{\mathfrak{r}}d^2\mathbf{r'}\bigg]
\end{align}
Which I do not understand *much* more than the more special case. Basically, I want to understand why, and how we define them as such, which helps to understand it's proper meaning.

Comment: I don't understand the question "how one would define them in such a way as that above".

Comment: Are you sure you have written your equations correctly? You have $A(r) = \phi(r)$.  If $\phi$ is the scalar then it only has one component where $A$ has three.

Comment: Have a look at the two derivations [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Helmholtz_decomposition#Derivation), you can see the decomposition into irrotational and solenoidal arises as a by-product of the derivation, it's not presumed that this should be the case.